# rails association callback AFTER association saves

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Conversation` with messages and participants

in a controller i'm building and saving

```
conversation = Conversation.new(params)
conversation.participations.build(params)
conversation.messages.build(params)
conversation.save
```

My `Message.rb` has an after_create callback.

on `save` i would expect all the objects to be persisted, And then all their callbacks to be triggered.

What i'm finding is the message callback is firing before the participations have persisted.

Comment: How are you checking that participations have been persisted - don't forget commit won't be run till the whole transaction is complete - that happens after the `after_create` callback. Perhaps you want to be using `after_commit` instead - difficult to attempt a solution because you haven't provided any indication of what the problem or requirement for this is.

Comment: I have a transaction around the save of all the objects. I think the lesson here is: if you need to make sure the objects are persisted then use `after_commit`

Comment: @David if you move your comment to an answer then i'll mark it correct.

Comment: Thanks done so :) glad it was of help. Wasn't entirely sure it would be hence it originally being a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget commit won't be run till the whole transaction is complete - that happens after the `after_create` callback. Thus your objects won't be fully persisted to the database until the successful completion of `conversation.save`

Perhaps you want to be using `after_commit` instead - difficult to say if this would resolve your question as its not clear from your question what the motivation is or where you are experiencing any issues.